# How to not execute additional code in OnActionExecutionAsync for specific actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I created a base controller class called `BaseController` in my ASP.NET Core 6 project which includes some basic functionality which I need in my other controllers. I also run some additional code in the `OnActionExecutionAsync` method inside the `BaseController` which I would otherwise have to run in every single controller action. However, in some rare cases I do not want to run this code before an action. One example for this are any authentication/login related actions. Is there a way how I can skip running the additional code via `OnActionExecutionAsync` for specific controller actions? I am thinking of something similar to how I can use `[AllowAnonymous]` to allow access to specific actions for non-authenticated users.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how do you design your `BaseController`, but usually we custom [Action Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#action-filters) if you want do anything before the action executes.

**First way** you can custom `ActionFilterAttribute` and add this attribute on the action which you want to run any other additional code.

```
public class CustomActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var controllerName = context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        string action = context.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
       //xxxxxxx.Query["YourQueryStringName"].....
        var query = context.HttpContext.Request.Query["tenantID"].ToString();

       //do your stuff....
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class TestController:BaseController
{
    [CustomActionFilter]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**Second way** you can get your request controller and action name in the method to make them as a condition：

```
public class CustomActionFilter: IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var controllerName = context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        string action = context.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        if(controllerName!="xxx"&&action!="xxx")
        {
            //do your stuff...
        }
    }
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        
    }
}
```

**Note:**

If you want to get the controller and action value, be sure you configure the route template like below:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: Thanks! The reason why I implemented `OnActionExecutionAsync` in the `BaseController` and not in a filter is that I need to write to a few fields/properties which I then use in the child controllers. I couldn't find an easy way to do the same thing in a custom filter (at least not without doing something hacky). I like your first solution but I see the same problem there. How can I access controller properties in `OnActionExecutionAsync` with that solution (without using Reflection or doing anything similar)?

Comment: Hi @Chris, for the first solution, why do you want to access controller properties? Actually if you set the attribute on action, only this action can invoke the `OnActionExecutionAsync `.

Comment: My application has to support multitenancy. In order to make this work, I have to read the tenant ID that the frontend provides as a query argument, validate it (check if the user is actually allowed to access this tenant) and then I set it as a property in the `BaseController` which I can then use in the controller actions when interacting with the business logic and data access layers. If I don't do it this way, I would have to add this code in every single action (or at least call 1-2 functions that run this code) which would result in a lot of redundant code.

Comment: Hi @Chris, ok, I got it. BTW, what is your OnActionExecutionAsync like? Is it similar with what I did in the first solution? Actually I mean do you have `ActionExecutingContext ` in `OnActionExecutionAsync `. Also for confirm, you want to get the tenant ID which is query string in url,right?

Comment: Hi @Chris, I have updated my answer. Pls check.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't exactly what I was looking for. Your second solution seems more suitable but I want to avoid hardcoding the action names (if possible). Also, ~95% of my controller actions need to run this additional code, while only a few of them don't need it. Therefore it would be much easier for me to specify for which controller actions I don't want to run it instead of adding an attribute to every single action where I do in fact want to run it (like in the first solution). Thanks for your efforts nevertheless.